Is there any QML algorithm that performs better than a classical one in practice?
As of today, is there any QML algorithm that performs better than a classical one in practice? I have been looking for quantum neural networks, quantum kernels and quantum CNN, but none so far have come up with a better-performing model than it's classical counterpart.

To my knowledge, there are no QML demonstrations that cannot be classically simulated. Since system size scaling of the training is a crucial component in "performing better" and not fundamentally understood, I think the short answer is no.

related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13368/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13531/55.

As a general comment, answering this question is made harder by "QML" being a somewhat undefined term. Assuming you refer to quantum algorithms to solve ML tasks, I'm not aware of formal proofs of advantage in practical applications. Most problems discussed https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3272 remain open, and the "heuristic methods" used today have the downside that gaining formal evidence of "quantum advantage" is really hard. You might say formal proofs aren't needed, but then you need to carefully define what "in practice" means, and how to compare quantum vs classical performances.

Thanks for the clarification and comments, it solves my question @glS
